Structure of points of elliptic curves in field with restricted ramification
Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and let $C$ be a curve over $k$. Let $E$ be a non-constant elliptic curve over $k(C)$. Taking the Néron model of $E$ and removing the singular fibers gives a smooth fibration $\mathcal{E}\to U$ for $U$ open in $C$. Let $L/k(C)$ be the splitting field of all of the prime to $p$ torsion of $E$. It has the property that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k(C))$ is a quotient of $\pi_1(U)$. So the only primes that can ramify in $L/k(C)$ are those given by points in $C\setminus U$, but still $L/k(C)$ is an infinite algebraic extension.
Is there anything that can be said about the group structure of $E(L)$? For example, is $E(L)/E(L)_{\text{tors}}$ finitely generated?
Thanks in advance for anyone answering!

Probably this should be infinite. For each finite dimensional orthogonal representation $V$ of the Galois group of $L$, nontorsion rational points of $E \otimes V$ give nontorsion rational points of $E(L)$, and there should be a fifty-fifty shot of nontorsion rational points of $E \otimes V$ for parity reasons.  There will be infinitely many such $V$ and thus $E(L)/ E(L)_{\operatorname{tors}}$ should have infinite rank.

Maybe a way to make this rigorous is to use modular curves. for any $N$ prime to $p$, $E(L)$ admits a natural map from the group of rational points on the universal curve over the modular curve $X(N)$. So one just has to check that these can have arbitrarily large rank. The space where the cohomology classes of rational points live corresponds to modular forms of weight $3$, and every modular form whose $p$th Hecke coefficient vanishes gives a Frobenius eigenvalue on this cohomology which implies (under the Tate/BSD conjecture) a nontorsion rational point.

One should be able to check there are lots of such modular forms and then maybe the known progress towards BSD will be sufficient to get rational points.

Hi Will, thanks so much for the swift replies. I must say that I do not understand all the details, but I will try to do so. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.
